# value matching based on common names + max value of an additional field? (R)

Tags: r, pattern-matching, max

I'm trying to subset a dataframe for sons with a common father who have the heaviest weight. See the sample data below.

```
va <- c("tom", "john", "regis")
df1 <- data.frame(va)
names(df1) <- "names"

vb <- c("chris", "ned", "curt")
vc <- c("tom", "tom", "vince")
vd <- c(20, 30, 40)
df2 <- data.frame(vb, vc, vd)
names(df2) <- c("names", "father", "weight")
```

I can subset based on common names alone with:

```
df2[df2$father %in% df1$names,]
```

which returns:

```
names father weight
1 chris    tom     20
2   ned    tom     30
```

but how can I only return just this?

`[2]   ned    tom     30`

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` library you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  inner_join(df1, by = c('father' = 'name')) %>%
  group_by(father) %>%
  filter(weight == max(weight))
```